# different background colours in div tags

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if there is a more nice way to set 4 different background colours in CSS. I have to make the following setup:

[image: Design Setup]

Is there a more clean and nice code I can make beside this i made, or is this the only way to do it? The code is just looking really ugly after my opinion.

```
<div class="bg1"></div>
<div class="bg2"></div>
<div class="bg3"></div>
<div class="bg4"></div>



.bg1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.bg2 {
    background-color: red;
}
.bg3 {
    background-color: green;
}
bg4 {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: use `background-color` instead of `color`

Comment: Well for one, `color` won't do anything in this case, as it refers to the color of the text. You're looking for `background-color`. Also, I'm not sure what you're even asking. Is there a way to get your divs to be certain colors, without specifying the colors? ...would the page just "guess" the colors?

Comment: You won't get any more concise than specifying four background color rules

Comment: Sorry my mistake with the color. Is there a more clean way to specify the colours than I did, or would everybody else also do like I did?

Comment: What do you mean by "more clean way"? There isn't a more simplified way of specifying four different colors.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answers. I am gonna do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personnaly, I would do that:

```
<div class="square square-blue"></div>
<div class="square square-red"></div>
<div class="square square-green"></div>
<div class="square square-purple"></div>
```

and in CSS:

```
.square{
    border: 1px solid black; // and all params
}
.square-blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.square-green {
    background-color: green;
}
.square-purple {
    background-color: purple;
}
.square-red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

for more readability (a small usage of BEM - http://getbem.com/introduction/ ).

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of nth-child/nth-of-type here.

Check the following code snippet.

```css
.container div:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: red;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: green;
}
div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: purple;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg1"></div>
  <div class="bg2"></div>
  <div class="bg3"></div>
  <div class="bg4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add style='background-color: #123456' to each div, if you really had to because of some restriction of a templating engine (I can't imagine such a circumstance), but what you've got is fine in the context.

EDIT: What I mean by that is if you wanted to have, say a rainbow effect. In Perl/TemplateToolkit, I could see something like:

```
[% for ($code = 0; $code < $whatever_max_hex_is'; $code++) { %]
<div style='background-color: [%$code%]'></div>
[%END%]
```

Something like that. Totally untested, but I'm sure you get the drift.